# Array storing string along with float value in swift3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, xcode7.3

I am learning Swift, I have created an array in Playground project

```
var stringArray:[String] = ["sanoj","kashyap"] //creating array of type string
```

After this I created array like 
    `var stringArray:[String] = ["sanoj",2.2]` // shows me array which is correct (means it gives error)
but

```
var stringArray1 = ["sanoj",2.2] does not giving any array ?? why?
```

As per def of array :

> An array is an ordered collection that stores multiple values of the
>   same type. That means that an array of Int can only store Int values.
>   And you can only insert Int values in it.

[image]

```
Xcode:Version 7.3 (7D175)
OS: 10.11.6 (15G31)
```

checking array through enumeration seems working fine.

[image]

Why error not coming while creating array? Check in Xcode as well it's taking as same.

Comment: Does `var stringArray:[String] = ["sanoj",2.2]` compile? How `2.2` can be assigned to array of type String?

Comment: yes, it's compiled.

Comment: No, you don't understand how a playground works. `var stringArray:[String] = ["sanoj",2.2]` cannot compile.

Comment: Yes it cannot compile. It is declared as String explicitly.

Comment: I did not explained "// shows me array which is correct (means it gives error) but" for var stringArray:[String] = ["sanoj",2.2] I knew it's can not compile. It was incomplete. Down vote some de motivate :( I have corrected the sentence. And Down vote is coming after giving answer and accepting as well. means some missed too to read properly.

Answer (score 2):

As of you are using Xcode 7.3 means you are working with Swift 2.3 so that the second array `stringArray1` is type of `[AnyObject]`. That is the reason you are not getting error. In Swift 2.3 or above you can add different types of object in same array that has type `[AnyObject]`

In Swift 3 it is type of `[Any]` array.

Answer (score 2):

It is inferred as an array of AnyObject. Both String and Double can be cast up to AnyObject by bridging. So the array does still have just one element type!

Comment: the "An array is an ordered collection that stores multiple values of the same type" can be false which mentioned in blog? one way?

Comment: No it is not because that Array contains all object of type `AnyObject` and in swift `AnyObject` is also a type just like `String`, `Int`, `NSData` etc.